# Backbone.js & Require.js - App Components can't communicate with Router

Tags: backbone.js, namespaces, requirejs

I'm doing initial setup on a new Require/Backbone app, and I can't seem to get my "global resource" object to communicate with some sub-modules.  I suspect it has to do with some circular dependency, but I'm not sure where/why/how.

After all the shimmed items load in **configure.js**, the app is kicked off:

```
/* kick off */
define([ 
    'cxn/newUI/rr',
    'cxn/newUI/routers/mainRouter'
], function( app, MainRouter) {

    // create router
    app.router = new MainRouter({
        model: app
    });

    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true,
        root: app.rootURL
    });
});
```

**rr.js** is my "Resource Registry" where all the global app stuff is defined

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {

    // main namespace object
    var ResourceRegistry = {

        rootURL: '/',
        models: {},
        views: {},
        collections: {},
        router: {},
        eventBus: _.extend( {}, Backbone.Events ),
        tplCache: {}

    };

    return ResourceRegistry;
});
```

My **mainRouter.js** starts up, gets through route preparation, and loads a Main Controller:

```
define([
'cxn/newUI/rr',
'cxn/newUI/controllers/_mainAppController',
'cxn/newUI/controllers/homeController',
'cxn/newUI/controllers/inboxController'
], function( app, MainAppController, HomeController, InboxController ) {

function cleanup() {
    if (currentPage && currentPage.destroy) {
        currentPage.destroy();
    }
}

var currentPage;

var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        ''                  : 'index',
        'home'              : 'home',
        'messages'          : 'showInbox',
        'messages/:id'      : 'showMessage',
        'patient/:id'       : 'showPatient'
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.model = options.model;
        this.eventBus = app.eventBus;
        this._listenForEvents();
    },

    // route definition methods
    index: function() {
        MainAppController.initialize({ eventBus: app.eventBus });
        return this;
    },

    ....
```

Finally, my main controller loads up and executes a "postInitialize" hook, where everything comes to a screeching halt.

```
define([
'cxn/newUI/rr',

'cxn/newUI/controllers/_baseController',

'cxn/newUI/views/_mainAppView/pageHeaderView',
'cxn/newUI/views/_mainAppView/mainContentView',
'cxn/newUI/views/_mainAppView/pageFooterView',
'cxn/newUI/views/_mainAppView/pageBottomDrawerView'

], function( app, Controller, PageHeaderView, MainContentView, PageFooterView, PageBottomDrawerView ) {

// Define the "new" collections/models/etc to pass to the controller here

// Define the controller
var MainAppController = new Controller({

    name: '_mainAppController',

    app: app,

    postInitialize: function() {

        app.eventBus.on('mainContentArea:loaded', function(route) {
            if (!route) {
                return app.router.navigate('home');
            }
            else {
                return app.router.navigate(route);
            }
        });

        //this._setupDocumentReady();
    },
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'navigate'`

I can see by setting a breakpoint in Chrome Dev Tools that "app.router", despite being defined in the initial kickoff, is not part of my global namespace, and therefore can't be used by the Controller.  Am I missing something?  Did I not define this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the last part of your mainRouter.js ...
A stupid question: did you add

```
return MainRouter;
```

at the end?

Comment: I did return the MainRouter, yes.